# Trying to find the longest substring without repeating characters

Tags: python

For example, if the string was `"pwwkew"`, the longest substring without repeating characters would be `"wke"`.

```
def longest_non_repeating_substring():
    count = 0
    current_longest = 0
    consideration = []
    possible_longest = []
    while count > len(string):
        current_char = string[count:count+1]
        consideration.append(current_char)
        for i in range(len(consideration)):
            if current_char == consideration[i]:
                possible_longest.append(current_longest)
                current_longest = 0
                del consideration[:]
                consideration.append(current_char)
        current_longest += 1
        count += 1
    return max(possible_longest)

longest_non_repeating_substring("pwwkew")
```

So, I iterate through the string one character at a time. At each character, I add it to my array consideration, and check if that current character already exists there. If it does, I reset the array consideration, make current longest zero, and leave in the current character in the array. If the current character isnt there then I increase the counter and the length of the current longest. It seems very logical to me, but this is wrong. Anyone know what gives?

Comment: you need to keep track of the overall longest then check if the current longest is larger than overall. If it is you replace it. With this code current longest will only be 1 unless the last n characters doesn't terminate and will only be correct if it's the longest

Comment: alright, I believe that is the thing I was overlooking the entire time, thanks.

Comment: There are several mistakes in the code, but first of all your `while` is never executed because `count > len(string)` is `False`, and so your code just jumps over `while` resulting in returning `0`.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter How about this where in the if statement, I treat it as its the possible longest, and then at the end, i take the maximum value?

Comment: *"check if that current character already exists there. If it does, I reset the array consideration, make current longest zero"* - This is logically wrong. For example, if your string is `abcade` then the longest substring without repeating characters is `bcade` of length 5, but if you reset to 0 when you see the second `a` then you will not count all 5.

Comment: but, i save the possible longest length to another list, and at the end I take the max in that list so shouldn't that work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the given code looks a little bit complicated. You could try to use something similar to this:

```
def longest_non_repeating_substring(string):
    count = 0
    current_longest = []
    current_candidate = []

    # Iterate over all characters in the string
    while count < len(string):
        current_char = string[count:count+1]
        
        # Check if we have a duplicate
        if current_char in current_candidate:
            # if so create a new candidate with the substring after the duplicate
            index_duplicate = current_candidate.index(current_char)
            current_candidate = current_candidate[index_duplicate+1:]

        # Append current character to candidate
        current_candidate.append(current_char)
            
        # Check if candidate is longer than what we had before; if so make candidate current longest
        if len(current_candidate) > len(current_longest):
            current_longest = current_candidate

        count = count +1
    
    # Convert list of current_longest to string
    current_longest_str = ''.join(current_longest)
    return current_longest_str


string = 'pwwkew'
longest = longest_non_repeating_substring(string)
print(longest) # Output: wke
```

Comment: this is cool, a couple python methods i didnt know existed such as the .index and .join, thanks

Comment: you're welcome! The problem is well known I think. If you are looking for more solutions there is a [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/length-of-the-longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/) that explains different algorithms for your problem.

Comment: okay thanks, im looking at the tutorial but this seems very NOT computer science to me, to cheese it buy means of studying some knonw algo for something simple instead of figuring it out yourself :( but at this point ill just accept that i have to do it lmao

Answer (score 0):

I see that others already pointed you in the right direction. I propose the following solution:

```
def longest_non_repeating_chars_substring(string: str):
  longest_substring = None
  current_substring = ''
  for i, char in enumerate(string):
    if i > 0:
      if char != string[i - 1] or current_substring == '':
        current_substring += char
      else:
        longest_substring = current_substring
        current_substring = char
    else:
      current_substring += char
  if len(current_substring) > len(longest_substring):
    return current_substring
  return longest_substring
```

Let me know of your thoughts!

Comment: You can also use try except instead of the first if.

Comment: Hi, I can't upvote because of my new account, Thanks for taking the time to show me your idea. I'm just now hell bent on figuring out where im going wrong since my solution surely cant be that bad but it appears so

Comment: @questionaire in my opinion your solutions seems too complicated in relation to your problem need. Try to keep it simple! Best regards.

Comment: well i thought my solution was simple, do you know why it doesnt work? I can't find the bug

Comment: You don't need two loops to solve your problem, for me, that's the main point.